# Android AsyncTask error, attempting to assign weaker access privileges.

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm stuck with this problem, I continue to receive the following error:

> 'processFinish(Boolean)' in 'Anonymous class derived from
>   MainActivity.AsyncGETRequestProcess.AsyncResponse' clashes with
>   'processFinish(Boolean)' in
>   MainActivity.AsyncGETRequestProcess.AsyncResponse'; attempting to
>   assign weaker access privileges ('packageLocal'); was public.

What I'm trying to accomplish is, run AsyncTask from inside `MainActivity` after I receive the data from an Intent.

Here is the onResume code where I receive the error, and where the Asynctask gets called:

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("cb.MainActivity.WebServiceReceiver.ReturnedReceivedDataFilePath");
        receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                //Get message from WebServiceReceiver Intent
                String ReceivedDataFilePath = intent.getStringExtra("WebServiceReceiver_ReturnedReceivedDataFilePath");


                new AsyncGETRequestProcess(new AsyncGETRequestProcess.AsyncResponse(){
                      //THE ABOVE ERROR HAPPENS HERE... processFinish
                      @Override
                      void processFinish(boolean success){
                        if(success){
                            MainActivity.getInstance().txtStatus.setText("Loading screen...");
                            Intent RouteScreenActivityIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.getInstance(), RouteScreenActivity.class);
                            MainActivity.getInstance().startActivity(RouteScreenActivityIntent);
                        }else{
                            //ERROR MSG
                        }
                        //Stop the spinner in MainActivity
                        MainActivity.getInstance().MainActSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        MainActivity.getInstance().txtStatus.setText("");
                    }
                }).execute(ReceivedDataFilePath).get();

            }
        };
```

Here is my `AsyncGETRequestProcess Class` which extends AsyncTask:

```
 //THE FOLLOWING CLASS RESIDES WITHIN MainActivity Class...
 public static class AsyncGETRequestProcess extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        public interface AsyncResponse {
            void processFinish(boolean success);
        }

        public AsyncResponse delegate = null;

        public AsyncGETRequestProcess(AsyncResponse delegate){
            this.delegate = delegate;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
            //Read the temp file location and create model of 'GET' Data Received.
            GetRequestRoot getRequestRootModel = Core.Helper.GetRootObjFromGetRequestTempFile(strings[0]);

            Boolean responseResult = ServerResponse.ProcessGetRequestResultModel(getRequestRootModel);

            if(responseResult)
            {
                Core.Data.ObjModel = Core.Helper.GetInputFileAsObject();
                if(Core.Data.ObjModel == null){
                    delegate.processFinish(false);
                }
                else{
                    delegate.processFinish(true);
                }
            }else{
                delegate.processFinish(false);
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result){

        }

    }
```

I'm also getting the following compile time error..

> Error:(108, 28) error: processFinish(boolean) in  cannot implement processFinish(boolean) in
>   AsyncResponse attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was
>   public

How can I fix this? I don't understand why its happening.

Comment: You are missing `public`

Comment: @Ferrybig Thats what i keep reading, but I've attempted to put public and nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make your method processFinish public:

```
           new AsyncGETRequestProcess(new AsyncGETRequestProcess.AsyncResponse(){
                  //THE ABOVE ERROR HAPPENS HERE... processFinish
                  @Override
                  public void processFinish(boolean success){
                  ^^^^^^
```

all interface methods are by default public

Comment: Oh jeez... I kept doing this but saw that the entire method highlighted in error.. I never bothered to mouse over and see that i was just missing a try/catch! Sigh...